# ReflectionHelper::assertGetterMethod() conflicts with Construction Heuristics requirement

Tags: optaplanner

I have the following:

```java
@CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerRef = @PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "..."))
@Override
public boolean isXyz() {
    return xyz;
}
```

Then I get the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entityClass (class ...) has a PlanningVariable annotated member (bean property ... on class ...) that returns a primitive type (boolean). This means it cannot represent an uninitialized variable as null and the Construction Heuristics think it's already initialized.
Maybe let the member (...) return its primitive wrapper type instead.
```

... see I really would change `boolean` to `Boolean`, but then I'll get the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The getterMethod (public java.lang.Boolean isXyz()) with a CustomShadowVariable annotation must have a primitive boolean return type (class java.lang.Boolean) or use another prefix in its methodName (isXyz).
```

It seems that the Construction Heuristics wants a nullable type so it can have a null initialization value, yet when provided with a Boolean object, the reflection helper assertion tries to validate it against the primitive type which fails.

Is this a defect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the method name to `getXyz` (full signature: `Boolean getXyz()`).

I'm only guessing because I don't have an example domain containing such shadow variable at hand. But looking at the `ReflectionHelper` code, this could be the solution. If that works, I'll try to improve the exception message.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing and it works because the only assertion done on a get prefixed method is whether the return type is not void (afaik). Just wondering if the assertions should take into account the wrapper classes as well for future situations like mine.